# how to know routing rules after ipsec VPN started?

Tags: ipsec

I have a ipsec vpn configured in /etc/ipsec.conf

```
conn ikev2vpn
    ikelifetime=60m
    keylife=20m
    rekeymargin=3m
    keyingtries=1
    keyexchange=ikev2
    ike=aes256gcm16-sha256-ecp521!
    esp=aes256gcm16-sha256!
    leftauth=eap-mschapv2
    eap_identity=xxx
    right=xxx
    rightauth=pubkey
    rightid=@xxx
    rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    auto=add
```

After I enable this setting with "ipsec up ikev2vpn".

All the traffic will be forwarded to the VPN.

I'm wondering how can I only forward specific traffic to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `rightsubnet` parameter (on the VPN server) to suit your outgoing traffic that you want to tunnel. Or if you can't change your server ipsec config, you need to add a traffic bypass policy on your client.